# swift stack view hide and show using code doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning iOS app development following a document "App development with swift", there is an example "PersonalityQuiz", I followed step by step.
  in one view control, there are two stack view in it, and both are hide first, then it will call the method updateSingleStack as shown to show the stackView:

```
func updateSingleStack(using answers: [Answer]) {
        singleStackView.isHidden = false
        singleButton1.setTitle(answers[0].text, for: .normal)
        singleButton2.setTitle(answers[1].text, for: .normal)
        singleButton3.setTitle(answers[2].text, for: .normal)
        singleButton4.setTitle(answers[3].text, for: .normal)
    }
```

but in fact nothing shows up.

and strange thing is that if I add a button in the viewControl, and add a Action to change the property singleStackView.isHidden, this stackView do show and hidden.

please let me know why is that? and how to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can post a minimal code that helps run and reproduce the issue. This would help get more accurate answers.

Comment: Hard to guess from what you have there but are you sure the function is being called?  Use "print" or a breakpoint to verify.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response. since I am new to app development, not sure how to share a runnable code here. I uploaded to GitHub: https://github.com/zhengqinggan/test.git.           thank you very much!

Comment: yes, I use print to print out the property of stackView.isHidden, and it do print out "false" as it is set

Answer (score 0):

ok, During adding the singleStackView, and overlay another multipleStackView, the installed checkbox was unchecked, I thought it was the same as isHidden = true in the code. But it is not, after I check the installed checkbox for both StackView, now, the code works.